# Google contacts using OAuth 2 on Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I want to list gmail contacts of  user using oAuth 2. I am able to get access token and refresh token by following this tutorial http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-oauth2-webview.html.

Now I want to get contacts list using access token and refresh token.

I am using [Oauth 2 play ground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and able to get the contacts on play ground. But how to get contacts using access token and refresh token in android code.

Comment: You may want to consider using [Android's native contacts APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) instead, since it includes Gmail contacts if they have added their Google account to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Solution from this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.

After your application obtains an access token, you can use the token to make calls to a Google API on behalf of a given user account or service account. To do this, include the access token in a request to the API by including either an access_token query parameter or an Authorization: Bearer HTTP header. When possible, the HTTP header is preferable, because query strings tend to be visible in server logs.

My Http Get request is:

GET https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000&alt=json

headers :

Authorization: Bearer 1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg

GData-Version: 3.0